# Free Book Nook - where to find the downloaded books?

Tags: apps

I got an app called Free Book Nook and I downloaded 3 free books to my phone, but have no clue where these books are placed. Also the app doesn't tell where to find them. I already looked in office, settings and storage along with data sense but found nothing.

Comment: This question is specific to a 3rd party app behavior. Have nothing to do with the Windows Phone O.S.

Consider get in touch with their support.

Comment: @VitorCanova Is this directly outside of the scope of the site? If so can you site the area? I agree it's on the edge, but could have some use for all of the others looking for advice on this issue. Plus it is about the Windows Phone version of the app.

Comment: @caschw Community always win.

Comment: On the app page it states "Please Note: You need the free Nook reading App for Windows Phone to read these books." I couldn't find such an app, does one exist?